# AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'gdk'

Tags: 14.04, gtk, python3, glade

I am porting python 2 to python 3.
When running application giving below error:
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'gdk'

Any idea to fix this!!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, without your code, I can't be sure, but this is most likely caused by an incorrect import statement. It's possible and highly likely that the import statement for Gdk changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

Try changing the `from gi.repository.Gtk import gdk` line to `from gi.repository import Gdk`. That's what I have in some of my code and it works fine. Make sure you get the capitalization correct though, `Gdk` is different from `gdk`.

Comment: I tried both. still same error. Could you please share list of packages needs to be install to work.

Comment: How to access gdk api e.g gtk.gdk.color_parser() how to modify for new Gdk?

Comment: @mrudula Can you edit your question with the part of your code that is importing the Gtk and Gdk *and* the entire Traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./vcontrol", line 37, in <module>
    import app_globals as g
  File "/home/vilter/vcontrol/lib/python/app_globals.py", line 282, in <module>
    COLOR_WHITE    = gtk.gdk.color_parse('#ffffff')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 320, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'gdk'

Comment: Ah. Try changing the code on line 282 in `app_globals.py` to `COLOR_WHITE = gdk.color_parse("#ffffff")`

Comment: code: Importing gtk and gdk modules                                                     from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk                                                       from gi.repository import Gdk                                                                            gdk=Gdk

Comment: How to import rtai ( customized) Modules in python3?

Comment: @mrudula That would be a separate question, and one that would fit better on [SO]. The way Stack Exchange works is you ask one question about one maybe two closely related things and then get answer for that one question. [See here for more](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). If my answer/comments fixed your problem then you can click that little check mark next to the answer. That'll let people know in the future that my answer helped solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31524/discussion-between-mrudula-and-rpi-awesomeness).

Comment: Alright!! Appreciate your suggestions. Thanks! It worked.